# Prawn requires ruby version 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I have **ruby version 1.9.2p290** installed and **prawn 0.13.0** in my **2** laptops.
When I tried to install the prawn on laptop A, it was successful and I'm able to use it but when I tried it to laptop B, it prompted an error that it requires ruby -v 1.9.3

[image]

How will I be able to solve this issue without changing the ruby version? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Downgrading the `prawn`

Comment: would there be any comparability issue if i merge 2 projects made of 2 different version of prawns?

Comment: you couldn't merge two project with usage of two separated version of the same library. Which problem of upgraging ruby? It had not major version change from 1.9.2 -> 1.9.3

Answer (score 4):

Reading the [Changelog](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/wiki/CHANGELOG#prawn-0130--20131215) for prawn 0.13.0, it says it has dropped support for Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 (See Item 4 on the Changelog link), I don't know how it worked for laptop A, but did you do it before 2 days ago? It seems prawn was just recently updated for version 0.13.0 on 12/15/2013

Perhaps using an older version of prawn would work? Prawn version 0.12.0 seems to support 1.9.2.

```
gem install prawn -v 0.12.0
```

or in your project Gemfile

```
gem 'prawn', '0.12.0'
```

Comment: Yes I did it 2 days ago

Comment: I don't know how it worked because the [.gemspec](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/blob/0.13.0/prawn.gemspec#L13) says it requires Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: I'm the maintainer of Prawn, and this is the correct answer. We stopped supporting Ruby 1.9.2 as of the 0.13.0 release. If you need 1.9.2 support, you can use Prawn 0.12.0, although it is a pretty old release.

Answer (score 0):

Find a version of prawn that works with ruby 1.9.2 and set that version in your gemfile